# ¿Es posible eliminar campos de la factura de prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

Tengo una duda y espero que me ayuden a solucionar. Quiero eliminar algunos campos de la factura que genera prestashop con el proceso contra entrega, pero no se si es posible, si alguien sabe como hacer este proceso agradezco mucho que me brinde la información.

Adjunto una imagen de la parte que quiero eliminar u ocultar de la factura.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto que puedes modificar las facturas a tu gusto. Prestashop almacena las plantillas en la carpeta `pdf` que se encuentra en el raíz:

[image: Carpeta donde se encuentran todas las partes]

Simplemente editando la parte correspondiente podrás ocultar/añadir lo que desees, así como cambiar su aspecto y demás.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en mi búsqueda también encontré que se pueden editar en classes, pdf.

Comment: Si claro, si quieres añadir contenido a mayores deberás editar las clases para dotarlas de estas características "custom" a mayores, saludos! :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información :D